# How to get the Standardise estimates, SE, Confidence intervals with upper and lower limits for the mixed effect models in Lmer?

Tags: r, lmertest

I'm running a multi-level linear mixed effects model with a four-way interaction of fixed effects and two within-subject random effects.

```
AUG25M1 <- lmer(RTNormalized~ Block *SeqType* Group *AgeRange + (Block+SeqType|ParticipantID), control=lmerControl(calc.derivs = FALSE,optCtrl=list(maxfun=100000)), REML = FALSE, data = mdf)
```

I'm interested in reporting the interaction effects of the model with model estimates. For example, **(β = xx , SE = xx  , t = xx , 95% CI [xxx-xxx] and p = )**

Because of the complexity of the model, I'm not able to get the vcov matrix, the correlation values, or the CI values by using the confint() function.

```
Error correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 24 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
         vcov(x)   if you need it
```

and the `confint()` function is taking too long to process and always ends up hanging or making r-studio unresponsive.

I appreciate any suggestions on trying alternative ways to obtain the above model estimates required while reporting in the scientific journal.

Many thanks!